# given datatable, possible to use repeater, gridview, etc

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to get datatable into report format below using Repeater, Gridview, DataList, etc.?

Given DataTable:

```
dept, section, title
-----------------------
IT,Tech,Tech1
IT,Tech,Tech2
IT,Dev,Dev1
IT,Dev,Dev2
HR,Ben,Spec1



Display Format for Repeater, DataList, GridView, etc.
IT
    Tech
      Tech1
      Tech2
    Dev
      Dev1
      Dev2
HR
    Ben
      Spec1
```

Comment: Yes of course. You will probably need to nest the repeaters to get that structure though.

Comment: you could use linq to group your data which will make it easier to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested repeater to fulfill this requirement, assuming no. of columns are fixed in the datatable.

You will have to put 3 repeaters.

example:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterDept" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterSection" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterTitle" runat="server">
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now, derive distinct Departments from your datatable and bind `repeaterDept` with that. On, `ItemDataBound` event, retrieve respective child sections of the binding department and bind it with `repeaterSection`. Follow the same for `repeaterTitle`.

I think, this should fulfill your requirement.

Comment: What are my options if the number of columns are variable?

Comment: @Rod: In case of variable no. of columns, it will become much complex. so, in that case, it is advisable to fetch table from source containing hierarchical data. e.g. you return just 2 columns like `Title, Parent` and binding nested repeater accordingly...